# Remove list of words from a string Series

Tags: python, string, substring, series

I have a list of words to remove:

```py
words_list_to_remove = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```

I want to remove these words from the string Series (`df`):

| My_strings |
| --- |
| first |
| abc |
| second |
| third |
| def |
| forth |
| ghi |
| jkl |

My goal `new_df`:

| My_new_strings |
| --- |
| first |
| second |
| third |
| forth |

I want to keep each element as a **string** and also **keep the index** of each element. I tried to convert both of them to `set` but did not work for me.

Any help would appreciate it!

Comment: `df[~df['My_strings'].isin(words_list_to_remove)]`. Reference: [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin), [pandas boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and pass your `words_list_to_remove` to it:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Define Pandas Series that holds your data
df = pd.Series(["first","abc","second","third","def","forth","ghi","jkl"])

print("before dropping:\n", df)

# Define list of strings to drop
words_list_to_remove = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']

# Only keep rows that are not in list
df = df[~df.isin(words_list_to_remove)]

print("\nafter dropping:\n", df)
```

As you can see in the output, the index is preserved as well:

```
before dropping:
0     first
1       abc
2    second
3     third
4       def
5     forth
6       ghi
7       jkl
dtype: object

after dropping:
0     first
2    second
3     third
5     forth
dtype: object
```

*Note: you would usually name a DataFrame as `df`, it would be better to rename your Series something else to avoid confusion.*